# Unkillable processes in macOS (Monterey 12.6.1)

Tags: macos

I’ve had this happening now twice for a couple of weeks. It could be since I upgraded to Monterey 12.6.1 … Here is what happens:

- I want to **exit** some application, so I go through the `Quit` menu item.
- Only, the application **does not quit**: all the windows close, but the little “running” marker stays on in the dock.
- Then I try `Force Quit` and it goes away - or so it seems
- But then I want to start the application again: the icon in the dock starts jumping up and down for a moment, but nothing happens (no windows open, nothing)
- After a moment, the icon stops jumping, and the right click has the `Force Quit` option, but Force Quit does not do anything: the application stays there. Same when using the Finder's Force Quit menu item.
- When I look at `ps -ael` I can see the process is there

This has happened to me a few times during the last few weeks: with **BBedit**, **Mail**. Today it happened again with **VS code**, and now again with **Console**. It also even happened once with the **Finder** itself.

The only way out is to reboot. I tried killing the process of the locked apps, but they do not get killed. Even `kill -9` fails to kill it.

It looks like something is locking up some processes that makes them “***unkillable***”.

**EDIT:**
I understand that signals are only delivered to a process running in user space, or when a process transitions from kernel space to user space. SIGKILL signal (`kill -9`) cannot be caught and ignored, so the only way it is being ignored is if the process has made a system call that has not returned, such as a network or I/O request that is stalled.

Comment: First of all: test the problem in Safe Boot mode (hold Shift at boot). Also, test the problem in a brand new user account. These tests will provide information about where the problem lies.

Comment: This is a (rare) problem that has occurred since at least 10.12. The only "fix" is to restart as the system appears to quickly degrade in that state. I can't figure out exactly why it happens, but it seems to be due to some IO process that gets borked. Network/HDD/External/CD/etc. and, specifically with finder, XtraFinder crashing.

Comment: This is what seems to be happening, yes. Thinking back, the problems started happening after I started using a new external ssd. I have it split in two partitions, one I use for TM backups, one I use to offload some big files. 90% of the use is for the TM backups.

I have stopped leaving it connected permanently, and the error has no longer occurred.